# Connecting Firebase and Carto

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cartodb, carto-mobile

I'm working on mobile SDK of Carto (Carto Maps) and I'm using Firebase Database. I'm taking location data from the Firebase and showing that data on map with markers. But I've heard instead of doing this all, you can just connect Firebase and Carto directly via Google Drive. Carto will itself handle the process of taking locations and putting markers there. But I can't figure out a way to do it. I'll be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can just connect Firebase and Carto directly via Google Drive.
>   Carto will itself handle the process of taking locations and putting
>   markers there.

CartoMobileSDK does not have such a feature. Doing it as you're doing is the correct way.

CARTO's web platform, on the other hand, definitely has some Google Drive support, but automatically populating your map with markers from FireBase seems a bit fat fetched. Could you tell me where you heard about it?